# Algorithm complexity of Glibc string manipulation functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I realize that Glibc source code is extremely optimized and is in hand coded assembly. Are there any documents that have analyzed the algorithm complexities (Big O) of commonly used string manipulation functions like `strmcp`, `strncmp`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no documentation on that because it is straightforward. It is O(n) for `strcmp` and `strncmp`.